# ATOKやGoogle IMEでユーザ辞書の辞書ファイルをバッチ処理などで切り替えることは可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor, ime

お世話になっております。
EmEditorで以下のようなマクロが出来れば幸いです。EmEditor以外でも可能でしたらお願いいたします｡

マクロの過程でATOKやGoogle IMEでユーザ辞書の辞書ファイルを切り替えることは可能でしょうか？

いちいちフォルダの辞書ファイルを一時的に差し替えるとかのめんどくさいやり方ではない方法で探しています。

以下のような感じです。

●化学のユーザー辞書ファイルとしてATOK32U1.DICを使う
●旅行のユーザー辞書ファイルとてATOK32U2.DICを使う
●プログラミングのユーザー辞書ファイルとしてATOK32U3.DICを使う

このようにテーマが切り替わってショートカットキーとかバッチ処理などで自分のユーザー辞書の切替をしたいのです。
おもにEmEditorのマクロの過程で切り替えたいです。

ユーザー辞書のファイル名は旅行とかの日本語の名前は付けず、"ATOK32U1.DIC"でU1の部分の数値を入れ替えて切り替えできるようにしたいのです。

ユーザー辞書はAppDataのRoamingフォルダにあるようです。

C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Roaming\Justsystem\Atok32

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 何か「変換」動作に使うキーでその都度指定出来るのかも。[ATOKでユーザー辞書を切り替えて状況に応じた単語変換をしたい。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11159620306) の2つ目の回答。「通常、文字を入力してスペースキーで変換を行いますが、これは標準辞書セットが用いられています。スペースキーでなく、F2キーで変換すると、人名変換辞書セットで変換されます。初期の設定では5つの辞書セットが設定されていますが、もう5つ辞書セットを登録することができます。」とか、[追加した専門用語辞書をF5で使う](https://www.atok.com/dic/add.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。これはたいへん大きなヒントになりました。実験をやってみます。御厚意､感謝しております。